# What's wrong with my DFT implementation?

Tags: computational-physics, fourier-transform, discrete

I am trying to write an implementation of the discrete Fourier transform myself in Python, but for some reason, the transform that I get out is wrong. There are no fancy tricks in my implementation, I just directly took the discrete formula for a Fourier transform:

$$
X_k = \sum^{N-1}_{n=0} x_n \cdot e^{-\frac{i 2 \pi}{N} kn}
$$

and turned into code

```
def dft(tseries):
    N = tseries.size
    X = np.zeros(N, dtype=np.complex)
    for k in range(N):
        val = 0
        for n in range(N):
            val += tseries[n] * np.exp(-(2 * np.pi * 1j * k * n) / N)
        X[k] = val
    return X
```

I then use this function with the following code:

```
# Signal
Omega = 25 # Signal has one frequency of exactly 25 Hz, well below Nyquist frequency
t = np.linspace(0, 10, 500)
y = np.sin(Omega * t)

# Sampling Interval
Ts = np.mean(np.diff(t))
# Sampling Frequency
Fs = 1 / Ts
# Nyquist Frequency
Fn = Fs / 2 
# Signal Length
L = y.size 
 # Fourier Transform (Normalised)
ft_y = dft(y) / L

Fv = np.linspace(0, 1, int(np.fix(L / 2)) + 1) * Fn # Frequency Vector
Iv = np.arange(Fv.size); # Index Vector

f = plt.figure()
plt.plot(Fv, 2*np.abs(ft_y[Iv]))
plt.xlabel('Frequency (Arbitrary Units)')
plt.ylabel('Amplitude (Arbitrary Units)')

peak_f = Fv[np.argmax(2*np.abs(ft_y[Iv]))]
print(f"Peak at {peak_f} Hz")
```

**But this returns a plot centered about 4 Hz, rather than the expected 25.**

I've put this code into a shared Colab notebook so it can be easily looked at.

https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1Z7BEPaGn9f6YvwU8yPNbOFHrn4-mgYIP?usp=sharing

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: @MassimoOrtolano - Oh dear... Clearly out of coffee.

Comment: Implementation details of computational tasks are [off-topic](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) on this site: “While computational physics is on topic, we are not a programming site. If your question is about implementing computational code - in particular, if it's about writing, compiling, debugging or optimizing code, or about a specific language or library - then it is off topic.”

Comment: Is there no fft in a library? Also this is off-topic.

Comment: @G.Smith thanks, I didn't know questions of this nature were not allowed. In the future, I'll use scicomp.SE, which I just now discovered exists :)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it belongs to another SE site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably plotting $\omega$ and not $f$.

$$\omega = 2\pi f$$

so $$25\, \mathrm{rad}\cdot \mathrm{Hz} = 2\pi \cdot 4 \,\mathrm{Hz}.$$

Comment: So simple, of course. I was able to fix the code with `Fv = np.linspace(0, 1, int(np.fix(L / 2)) + 1) * Fn * 2 * np.pi`. Thank you kindly.